# Laravel 5.2 Cache Tags not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using **Laravel 5.2** Cache with memcached driver.

Was trying to implement the **Cache::tags** into my project but doesn't seems to be working.

But it works well when I am using

```
Cache::put('user_1', $user, 600);
```

Here is my code

```
Cache::tags('user')->put('user_1', $user, 600);
```

and I've tried using

```
Cache::tags(['user'])->put('user_1', $user, 600);
```

as it mentioned in the API docs saying it supported **array|mixed $names**

Not sure if anyone out there having the similar issue like me?

Comment: Tried same code with memcached - works just fine. Unfortunately there might be some issues with your config.

Comment: Hi @GiedriusKiršys , do you mind to show me your config file settings? I changed the cache_driver to use memcached and also using the default config settings for memcached in cache.php.

Comment: It's pretty much default, only changed `CACHE_DRIVER` to `memcached` in `.env`.

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys when you obtain the cached data, are you using Cache::has('user_1'); ?? or Cache::tags('user')->has('user_1');

Comment: I use `Cache::tags('user')->get('user_1');` to get data from cache.

Comment: OK @GiedriusKiršys thank you for the assists. It is working now, I missed out the tags when obtain cached data.

Answer (score 3):

This got me quite confused as well. When using cache tags with Laravel, to fetch the stored data from the cache, you need to specify the used tag(s).

E.g. when storing data like this:

```
Cache::tags('user')->put('user_1', $user, 600);
```

This won't fetch the data back:

```
Cache::get('user_1');
```

But this will:

```
Cache::tags('user')->get('user_1');
```

The behaviour is still the same with Laravel 5.4 (current version at the time of writing).